# How to avoid escape characters outputted to log file with logging?

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to color level names like INFO, WARNING, and so on but the problem is when a message is logged to the log file - there are weird characters. However, it gets printed out perfectly fine to the console.

Code:

```
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("log.txt"),
        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    ]
)

 logging.addLevelName(logging.INFO, "\033[1;31m%s\033[1;0m" % logging.getLevelName(logging.INFO))

logging.info("This is just an information for you")
```

This prints the level name "INFO" with color, but the output is:

```
2022-04-05 02:44:52,741 [[1;31mINFO[1;0m] This is just an information for you
```

How can this be fixed?

EDIT:

```
logging.addLevelName(logging.INFO, "\033[1;94m%s\033[1;0m" % logging.getLevelName(logging.INFO))
logging.addLevelName(logging.WARNING, "\033[1;93m%s\033[1;0m" % logging.getLevelName(logging.WARNING))
logging.addLevelName(logging.ERROR, "\033[1;91m%s\033[1;0m" % logging.getLevelName(logging.ERROR))
```

Comment: Hi, where are you viewing the file that you see those characters? For me it also shows correctly on the command line, and if I open the log file with `less`. However, if I open it with a gui text editor, I see the characters.

Comment: I view it with a notepad, or in Py Charm. Normally, the characters appear.

Comment: Check this out https://galea.medium.com/python-logging-example-with-color-formatting-file-handlers-6ee21d363184

Comment: @Cassano, I've posted an answer showing how we do it in the package I maintain (open-source).

Comment: @Cassano, I've updated my answer with a full solution, that you should be able to use directly.

Comment: @Cassano, I've just been reading the details on bounties, and I think I should have posted the complete working version as a new answer, instead of updating this one; it doesn't sound like answers posted prior to a bounty being set are awarded the bounty automatically, even if they are accepted. I'm going to post it as a new answer, if you could accept the new version, instead? Then I'll either un-update the original one so they're not repeating each other, or remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated to have individual colours assigned to each level.** To change colours, all is needed is to replace the corresponding number in `set_colours()` to the desired value.

Here's something that could be used directly to produce the logging you want:

```py
import logging
import re
import time
import sys

def set_colour(level):
    """
    Sets colour of text for the level name in
    logging statements using a dispatcher.
    """
    escaped = "[\033[1;%sm%s\033[1;0m]"
    return {
        'INFO': lambda: logging.addLevelName(logging.INFO, escaped % ('94', level)),
        'WARNING': lambda: logging.addLevelName(logging.ERROR, escaped % ('93', level)),
        'ERROR': lambda: logging.addLevelName(logging.WARNING, escaped % ('91', level))
    }.get(level, lambda: None)()


class NoColorFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """
    Log formatter that strips terminal colour
    escape codes from the log message.
    """

    # Regex for ANSI colour codes
    ANSI_RE = re.compile(r"\x1b\[[0-9;]*m")

    def format(self, record):
        """Return logger message with terminal escapes removed."""
        return "%s %s %s" % (
            time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()),
            re.sub(self.ANSI_RE, "", record.levelname),
            record.msg,
        )

# Create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__package__)

# Create formatters
logformatter = NoColorFormatter()
colorformatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")

# Set logging colours
for level in 'INFO', 'ERROR', 'WARNING':
    set_colour(level)

# Set logging level
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Set log handlers
loghandler = logging.FileHandler("log.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf8")
streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

# Set log formatters
loghandler.setFormatter(logformatter)
streamhandler.setFormatter(colorformatter)

# Attach log handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(loghandler)
logger.addHandler(streamhandler)

# Example logging statements
logging.info("This is just an information for you")
logging.warning("This is just an information for you")
logging.error("This is just an information for you")
```

This has the colour when it outputs to `stdout`, but not in the log file. The only difference between the logging statements this outputs, and those from your original code, is that `%(asctime)s` doesn't seem to work outside of a `logging.Formatter` object, so I've used `time` instead; the output is the same, except there aren't any milliseconds.

Comment: This works well, but the thing is I need colors for each different level, you know...? That's what my initial code does. I don't want a general color for all levels. Also yes, I will do as you say, no worries.

Comment: @Cassano, Can you share the colour codes you are trying to use for the different levels? I was basing this on your MWE, which only shows stuff for INFO, and thus only uses one colour, but altering it to do multiple shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: @Cassano, try that. And please remember to un-accept the old answer and accept this one instead, as that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Thank you! Might you please take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811155/add-a-new-level-with-colored-levels-logging

Comment: Thanks for the code. Note however that you should be using `record.getMessage()` instead of `record.msg`. Otherwise, your logger will not support lazy logging, e.g. `logging.info('processing %s', job)` would output `processing %s` and not replace the placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

---

### Original answer (not fully-functional; see accepted answer):

The characters appear in gui text editors (but not on the command line—depending on the shell being used) because they don't understand ASCII escape sequences—unless they've been specifically configured to do so.

You can add code to remove those characters when they are written to the `log` file:

```py
import logging
import logging.config
import re
import sys

from argparse import Namespace
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Optional

class NoColourFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    """Log formatter that strips terminal colour escape codes from the log message."""

    ANSI_RE = re.compile(r"\x1b\[[0-9;]*m")

    def format(self, record):
        """Return logger message with terminal escapes removed."""
        return "[%s] [%s]: %s" % (
            record.levelname,
            record.name,
            re.sub(self.ANSI_RE, "", record.msg % record.args),
        )
```

and use it something like this:

```py
# same file as above

def config_logger(args: Optional[Namespace] = None) -> None:

    logger = logging.getLogger(__package__)

    # other code

    logformatter = NoColourFormatter()
    loghandler = logging.FileHandler(args.logfile, mode="w", encoding="utf8")

    loghandler.setFormatter(logformatter)
    logger.addHandler(loghandler)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than overriding the level names globally, I would apply colouring in a specific formatter, and set that formatter on the handlers that required colouring.

```py
class ColouredFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    _lookup = {
        logging.INFO: "\033[1;94m%s\033[1;0m",
        logging.WARNING: "\033[1;93m%s\033[1;0m",
        logging.ERROR: "\033[1;91m%s\033[1;0m",
    }

    def format(self, record):
        result = super().format(record)
        # Operate on the result rather than record attributes to
        # avoid corrupting output for subsequent loggers.
        formatted_levelname = self._lookup[record.levelno] % record.levelname
        result = re.sub(rf'\[({record.levelname})\]', formatted_levelname, result, count=1)
        return result


streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
streamhandler.setFormatter(ColouredFormatter(fmt="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s"))

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        streamhandler,
        logging.FileHandler("so71744086log.txt"),
    ]
)
```