# Add a new colored level logging

Tags: python, logging

So this code outputs level names with colors (default levels), and I'd like to add extra levels of my own, and then give them a custom color.

Code:

```
import logging
import re
import time
import sys

def set_colour(level):
    """
    Sets colour of text for the level name in
    logging statements using a dispatcher.
    """
    escaped = "[\033[1;%sm%s\033[1;0m]"
    return {
        'INFO': lambda: logging.addLevelName(logging.INFO, escaped % ('94', level)),
        'WARNING': lambda: logging.addLevelName(logging.ERROR, escaped % ('93', level)),
        'ERROR': lambda: logging.addLevelName(logging.WARNING, escaped % ('91', level))
    }.get(level, lambda: None)()


class NoColorFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """
    Log formatter that strips terminal colour
    escape codes from the log message.
    """

    # Regex for ANSI colour codes
    ANSI_RE = re.compile(r"\x1b\[[0-9;]*m")

    def format(self, record):
        """Return logger message with terminal escapes removed."""
        return "%s %s %s" % (
            time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()),
            re.sub(self.ANSI_RE, "", record.levelname),
            record.msg,
        )

# Create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__package__)

# Create formatters
logformatter = NoColorFormatter()
colorformatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")

# Set logging colours
for level in 'INFO', 'ERROR', 'WARNING':
    set_colour(level)

# Set logging level
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Set log handlers
loghandler = logging.FileHandler("log.txt", mode="a", encoding="utf8")
streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

# Set log formatters
loghandler.setFormatter(logformatter)
streamhandler.setFormatter(colorformatter)

# Attach log handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(loghandler)
logger.addHandler(streamhandler)

# Example logging statements
logging.info("This is just an information for you")
logging.warning("This is just a warning for you")
logging.error("This is just an error for you")
```

What I want to accomplish is a new level, but with its unique color.

Here's the code on how I accomplish adding a new level:

```
def success(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(70):
        logging.log(70, msg)

logging.addLevelName(70, "SUCCESS")
logging.success = success
logging.Logger.success = success
```

The above code works fine normally but does not include any color. How can I add this code to have a new level, but with a different color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires the addition of a handful of lines, including this block (with the addition of another line to set the integer value for `logging.SUCCESS`:

```py
def success(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(70):
        logging.log(70, msg)

logging.addLevelName(70, "SUCCESS")
logging.SUCCESS = 70   # similar to logging.INFO -> 20
logging.success = success
logging.Logger.success = success
```

I've indicated the lines that have been added/modified here. To add further additional levels, defining the same structures for the new ones, and modifying the `for` loop and `set_colour()` functions should be enough.

```py
import logging
import re
import time
import sys

def set_colour(level):
    """
    Sets colour of text for the level name in
    logging statements using a dispatcher.
    """
    escaped = "[\033[1;%sm%s\033[1;0m]"
    return {
        'INFO': lambda: logging.addLevelName(logging.INFO, escaped % ('94', level)),
        'WARNING': lambda: logging.addLevelName(logging.ERROR, escaped % ('93', level)),
        'ERROR': lambda: logging.addLevelName(logging.WARNING, escaped % ('91', level)),
        'SUCCESS': lambda: logging.addLevelName(logging.SUCCESS, escaped % ('31', level))   # new
    }.get(level, lambda: None)()


class NoColorFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """
    Log formatter that strips terminal colour
    escape codes from the log message.
    """

    # Regex for ANSI colour codes
    ANSI_RE = re.compile(r"\x1b\[[0-9;]*m")

    def format(self, record):
        """Return logger message with terminal escapes removed."""
        return "%s %s %s" % (
            time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()),
            re.sub(self.ANSI_RE, "", record.levelname),
            record.msg,
        )

def success(msg, *args, **kwargs):   # new
    if logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(70):   # new
        logging.log(70, msg)   # new

# Create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__package__)

# Create formatters
logformatter = NoColorFormatter()
colorformatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")

# Create new level
logging.SUCCESS = 70   # new
logging.success = success   # new
logging.Logger.success = success   # new

# Set logging colours
for level in 'INFO', 'ERROR', 'WARNING', 'SUCCESS':   # modified
    set_colour(level)

# Set logging level
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Set log handlers
loghandler = logging.FileHandler("log.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf8")
streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

# Set log formatters
loghandler.setFormatter(logformatter)
streamhandler.setFormatter(colorformatter)

# Attach log handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(loghandler)
logger.addHandler(streamhandler)

# Example logging statements
logging.info("This is just an information for you")
logging.warning("This is just an information for you")
logging.error("This is just an information for you")
logging.success("This is just an information for you")
```